# Create a new object extending a trait and using early definition syntax

Tags: scala

How to create an objectthat extends a trait and uses early definition syntax?

Let's say we have two traits:

```
trait Trait {
  val value : String
}

trait Simple
```

Let's say we have also a simple class:

```
class Class
```

We can create a new object of type `Class` and make it extend a `Simple` trait:

```
new Class extends Simple
```

Is it possible to create a new object of type `Class` that extends the `Trait` and uses the early definition syntax to set `value` member? I tried something like:

```
     new Class  extends { override val value = "42" } with Trait
```

But this gives a syntax error:

> Error:(12, 17) ';' expected but 'extends' found.
>          new Class extends { val value = "42" } with  Trait

Comment: Can you clarify a bit more what you're trying to do? Why can't you just have this set up like a normal class? I suspect you want a lazy val, but can't find anything on the syntax you're referring to.

Comment: @Ethan Ooops, I meant early definition syntax. Actually, I have been just learning scala and just wondering, whether one can use that syntax when creating a new object.

Comment: Why can't you override the value in the body?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
trait T { val value: String }
class C
new C with T { val value = "ok" }
```

Comment: Can you add some context around your answer?

Comment: @atymic The only "context around" that I would have been able to produce could have been  "The right way to do that is ... ". But I was just afraid it would be just a redundant decoration on top of the implicit context determined by the question.  I could have stated that using Class and Trait for class and trait names is a bad practice (readability and eventual collision), but it's about teaching. I like reading answers that explain complex things, but I prefer minimalist answers to minimal questions. Thanks though.